# Facebook Api - Missing picture field in response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook Graph API to try to retrieve data such as user posts and user photos. I am able to successfully make the calls to the APIs. However, the response does not include any pictures in the json objects returned. I've checked the App permissions and I am sharing photos and posts with the app I am using to test the requests with.

In the graph request below I am expecting picture fields to be in the response.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to do was add the fields to the request. E.g. {fbUserId}/posts?fields=id,full_picture,message,created_time,description,is_expired